# Chocolatey Credentials Required

Tags: powershell, nuget, chocolatey, choco

I just installed chocolatey through nuGet using the following steps in the admin shell: [chocolatey nuget install](https://chocolatey.org/install#install-using-nugetexe-from-powershell). However, when I try to get any package, I am asked for credentials (which I assume is not meant to happen). Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

[chocolatey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5pt5.png)

Comment: You say that you installed Chocolatey through NuGet.  Can you confirm exactly what you did?  Did you follow the installation instructions here: https://chocolatey.org/install

Comment: Did you run the command `cinst` elevated?

Comment: Yes, I am using an admin shell, and here's what I followed: https://chocolatey.org/install#install-using-nugetexe-from-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a fix, but I found a work around. It is possible to download the *.nupkg files from https://chocolatey.org/packages and then run `choco install [packageFile]`, which doesn't require the server to be contacted and this avoids the permission issue.